is it possible to assign a new value to an existing variable name?
code from Is there any way to replace consecutive 'def'. in \definevar, aa=11 has been defined, but program goes wrong when I let aa=33
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_var_def:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be defined
  \xcn_var_set:n {#1}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_new_variable:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set_variable:nn { V }

\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/def }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }
\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/set }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_def:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/def } {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_set:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/set } {#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definevar{
  aa=11,
  aa=33, %! LaTeX Error: Floating point identifier 'aa' already defined.
  bb=22,
  CC=pi+2,
  DD=bb-CC
}

\begin{document}

\fpeval{aa}

\fpeval{CC+DD}

\fpeval{round(CC-2,4)}

\setvar{aa=-2}

\fpeval{aa+2}

\end{document}



it's not setting the new value that is causng an error it is    \fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str  when it is not new: you need to guard that and not do it if the variable is already defined

it seems work  when eliminate syntax
"\fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str"

@XCN that's what \setvar is doing. Notice however that you should declare every variable you're using, so you should use \fp_new_variable:V for the first time, and if you want to later change the value use \fp_set_variable:Vn. Also, there appears to be an existence check missing in the l3fp module, as there is no \fp_if_variable_exists:nTF.

@Skillmon you mean we can't use \ifx\something ? :-)

@Skillmon can you add \fp_if_variable_exists:nTF to the code. to be honest, I'm not familar with expl3.

@XCN I would, but it doesn't exist and has yet to be added to the language. I'll open a PR later today or this week which closes this omission.

waiting for your innovation.

I don't know, what is your goal but I can show you alternative approach based on \directlua LuaTeX primitive and \expr macro from OpTeX. No more special macros are needed.
\def\_decdigits{0}

\directlua{
   aa=11
   bb=22
   CC=math.pi+2
   DD=bb-CC
}

\expr{aa}

\expr{CC+DD}

\expr[4]{CC-2}

\directlua{aa=-2}

\expr{aa+2}

\bye


How to install OpTex on Windows ?

OpTeX is part of TeXlive or MikTeX. It means that you probably have it installed already. Run optex command instead pdflatex. That is all.

There is a reason why I rejected your proposed edit to add
  aa=33, %! LaTeX Error: Floating point identifier 'aa' already defined.

and it's precisely because this way of doing is wrong to begin with.
Maybe one could improve the code to allow just defining a variable in \definevar without giving a value (intended to be zero). But if you want to reset the value you have to use \setvar. Where's the problem?
If you have several \definevar commands an in one of them you try to use an already defined variable, you get an error, after which the output of the LaTeX rune is not to be trusted in any way. Fix the error and go on.

sorry, I didn't notice \setvar.
